# Share internet connection from iPad to iPhone via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth, internet-sharing

I can share my iPad's internet connection using Bluetooth to my Macbook Pro and my Android phone but my iPad and iPhone does not even seem to see each other when I try to pair them. I am abroad at the moment and have put a local SIM in my iPad and want to share the connection. Is this even possible? I can go iPad <-- BT --> some other device <-- WiFi --> iPhone but it feels stupid and is a waste of battery for no use at all!

Comment: Are you not able to use the iPad as a mobile hotspot? In that situation, just share the connection over WiFi instead of bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, but that is waste of battery.

Answer (score 1):

**personal hotspot without WiFi**

1. Activate Personal Hotspot in Settings
2. Disable WiFi

iOS and OS X devices will use Bluetooth when possible over WiFi, so no need for the above.